# Server.MapPath throws error when using web image cropping library

Tags: c#, asp.net, crop, server.mappath

I have an image stored on server at location:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imageupload\images
```

in my code i want to use an image from folder images so i am trying as follows:

```
Server.MapPath("/images/sample1.jpg")
```

But i am getting the error as:
[image]

Please help me to solve the error

As on several answer asking to post the code,it is as follows

**.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CS.Web.UI.CropImage" Namespace="CS.Web.UI" TagPrefix="cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <cs:CropImage ID="wci1" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wci1.Crop(Server.MapPath("/imageupload/images/sample1.jpg"));

        /*
         this part is just to show the image after its been cropped and saved! so focus on just the code above.
         */
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ImageUrl = "images/sample1.jpg?rnd=" + (new Random()).Next();  // added random for caching issue.
        this.Controls.Add(img);
    }
}
```

Crop method is from a .dll file i have used from http://imagecropping.codeplex.com/

Comment: Put the resolved path inside of a string variable, so that you can view and debug it. `string imgPath = Server.MapPath("/images/sample1.jpg");` What is the value of the variable `imgPath` now? Also note that the error occurs in the class `CropImage`, further down in the call to `.Crop(string path)`

Comment: You still aren't showing us the `Crop` code.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Its a method from .dll file i have used.http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There error is in the `CSA.Web.UI.CropImage.Crop` method, as described by the stack trace.

`Server.MapPath`, to my knowledge, will not return a null string (it'll throw an exception if it can't map - but not a `NullReferenceException`).

I'd suggest you look into the method I mention and possibly post the relevant code, too.

**EDIT:**

So, I had a quick look at the `Crop` code from [the CodePlex project](http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55276#470209) you mention and found the following lines (formatting mine):

```
private string ImagePath { get { return ViewState["ImageUrl"].ToString(); } }

drawing.Image image = drawing.Image.FromStream(
    new MemoryStream(
        System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(this.ImagePath)
        )
    )
);

cropedImage.Save(path);
```

Now, it seems to me that:

- Argument `Path` is not null*
- Argument `ImageUrl` *is* null**

*Though it might be 'incorrect' it isn't the problem right now.

**Meaning the call `ToString` is the breaking factor in this code.

Basically, the control doesn't have an image set to crop and this is evident in your own code:

```
//currently no ImageUrl set...
<cs:CropImage ID="wci1" runat="server" />

//your'e trying to crop here without an ImageUrl...
wci1.Crop(Server.MapPath("/imageupload/images/sample1.jpg"));
```

The fix is to specify an image via `ImageUrl`, AFAIK, however I can't see how to do so.

Comment: Yes, but Crop cannot map the file, as the location is invalid. So Server.MapPath isn't the problem.

Comment: @Theofanis Pantelides: Thanks for reiterating exactly what I said.

Comment: UpVote for thinking outside the box.

Comment: Sir so what should i do now in my project? Where do i need to modify?

Comment: @Ishan: I've updated the last part of my answer, see if this works for you.

Comment: wci1.ImageUrl is not available for this control. Image URL property is not there. What to do now?

Comment: @Ishan: Actually, looking at my own post again that makes sense (since `ImageUrl` is a private property). You need to find out **how** to set this value. Maybe try getting some support from the project contributors? If there documentation does not suffice then maybe you need to bring this up as a discussion with them.

Answer (score 1):

You have stored your images in `imageupload\images` but when you tried to grab them you forgot to add in the `imageupload` directory:

```
Server.MapPath("/imageupload/images/sample1.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you try this Server.MapPath("~/imageupload/images/sample1.jpg")

Comment: As you have updated your question now, its clear that problem is in croping and its not server.mappath issue.

Comment: @Ishan: Have you tried dumping `Server.MapPath("~/images/sample1.jpg")` to a string to see what it reports?

Comment: @Muhammad: The proper ~ mapping would be `"~/images/sample1.jpg"` as the project name "imageupload" would be handled by the ~. +1 anyway though :)

Comment: @Joel and verifying the existence of the file.

Comment: @Theo: Yes, that was going to be my next suggestion if Server.MapPath was producing the expected filename. The next item after that is to verify that the user account running the webserver in question has permission to access the file in a write capacity and that the file is not already in use by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative path instead:

```
Server.MapPath("images/sample1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using "~/images/sample1.jpg" for your source. the "~" is replace by the application name in the call to Server.MapPath

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://webcropimage.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/CS.WebControls/WebCropImage/CropImage.cs

Method Crop(), gives a path where to **save** the cropped image.

Which image should be cropped is stored in *wci1.ImagePath*

Please check if this value is *null*, and this should point out the problem.

As there is no `<Form runat="Server">`, maybe it cannot access the ViewState:

```
private string ImagePath { get { return ViewState["ImageUrl"].ToString(); } }
```

Comment: Which is elaborating on Mr. Muhammad's answer; to be fair.

Comment: 1) elaborate: add details to an existing idea.  2) my comment refers to the .aspx page being invalid, and not the .cs  3) you've already addressed the issue.

Comment: @Ishan: I am working with the same dll. how did u get this to work